# Xcode4 Workspace with Static library project & application project

Tags: ios, xcode4, workspace

I'm working on a project where I'm going to eventually have a library of code that will be used by multiple applications.  In reading though the documentation it sounded like creating an XCode4 workspace and 2 projects (1 library, and 1 application) was the way to go.

I did this and everything appeared to be working just great.  However, today I did a bunch of work on my library project and when I run my application to test my library changes it appears to always be including an older compiled version.  I'm at a loss, I added my library as a build target in my applications scheme and XCode tells me it's compiling the library, but its always linking to an old version.

Any help is greatly appreciated.  Am I missing something in how I set my workspace up?  Is there a build step that will force linking to my newly compiled .a?  I've even tried removing the dependency, cleaning, re-adding the dependency and building my app and I still get the same results.

Comment: Perhaps a specific compiled version was added in 'Link Binary With Libraries' under 'Build Phases'.

Comment: Please update your question with a description of exactly how your dependencies are set up (or do you let Xcode auto-detect), how exactly your built .a product is linked to your app, etc. The details here are important.

Comment: Thanks for the comments, I got back to my code today and did a clean and re-build and everything is linking appropriately again.  I think I must have been tired and doing something stupid yesterday.  To answer you question Joshua, I am letting XCode auto-detect.

Comment: Good news. Please post this as an answer and mark it accepted. A good SO citizen should clean up after themselves. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out XCode was doing everything right, and I wasn't.  Another clean all and recompile and everything is working as expected.

Answer (score 2):

I ran into same problem and my solution was to add

```
rm -f BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR/$EXECUTABLE_PATH
```

to the `build -> pre-actions` section (edit scheme, expand build and add pre-action).
Under `Provide build settings from` make sure to select your target project.
This will ensure correct env vars are configured when your script runs.
I'm using XCode 4.5.1.

Answer (score 1):

Additional information about this type of issue here:  [Static libraries in Xcode 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6074576/static-library-in-xcode4/6077012#6077012)