# How to combine object files (.o) to create static library (.a) for iOS?

Tags: c, ios, static

I have compiled a library and there are object files(.o). Now I want to combine them in a static library using ar. I am able to do that but when I add that file in iOS project it says the library is archive type while linking architecture is arm7. How do I get around this?

**Solved**

ar -crs libstatic.a *.o
Previously I was using the ar from iOS SDK and I guess thats why it was failing.

Answer (score 6):

```
ar -rcs libexample.a *.o
```

Link the library with the switch:

```
 -lexample
```

Answer (score 1):

The best resource by far I have found on the topic is here:

http://sgleadow.github.com/blog/2011/10/28/universal-static-libraries-and-frameworks-for-ios/

This is a lengthy process - but every step is essential to get this to work as expected.

Comment: Thanks but its not exactly what I am looking for.

Comment: Sorry - but in the end it is :).  If you are creating your static library for a single architecture - it is because your build settings are not properly configured.  You need to take a step back and setup your project according to these guidelines and your problem will go away.

Comment: I don't have any XCode project to begin with. Its a C library that I am trying to compile and inherently it doesn't produce a lib.a which usually the libraries produce when one makes them. Of course I don't know how to make changes in either configure or Makefile to force it to make a static lib.