# For VOIP call in iPhone SIP library gives linking error

Tags: iphone, ios, voip

I am working on `VOIP` call. For that I am linking `libmswebrtc.a` library. Its not working for my mac. While same code I checked with other mac, and its working. Following is error details:

> Undefined symbols for architecture armv7:
>     "_WebRtcSpl_MinValueW16Neon", referenced from:
>         _InitPointersToNeon in libmswebrtc.a(spl_init.o)

Comment: Where did you find libmswebrtc library? Maybe you misspelled the name?

Comment: mswebrtc is given by client.

Comment: My project have workspace. And in that workspace I have added my project. So, while building individual library, mswebrtc is getting build but for building target of my project, it gives error that mentioned above.

Comment: Check that you properly set `target dependencies` and `link binary with libaries`.

Comment: I have checked that. But its working for other mac. Any dependency of mac OS or else.

Answer (score 0):

This kind of error says that you not linked your library with your project.

I think that [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6124872/1263701) can help you.