# Setting up CocoaLibSpotify correctly?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoalibspotify-2.0

I´m using the Spotify API for my new iOS project and just finished the setup, but not sure I did this the right way.

I created a new project and added the *CocoaLibSpotify iOS Library.xcodeproj* by right clicking my project -> "Add Files...". So the CocoaLibSpotify project is embedded in my own project. I´ve also added it to Target Dependencies and Link Binary with Libraries.

The "Building iOS"-guide tells me to add a couple of frameworks and set some linker flags.

The CocoaLibSpotify project that I embedded already have these frameworks, should I add them to my project as well?

I also try to import *CocoaLibSpotify.h* by `#import "CocoaLibSpotify.h` but it does not find the file. `#import <CocoaLibSpotify.h>` works though.

Which header files should I import to my prjoject? (I can´t seem to find the "include" directory).

Comment: You must have messed up in some point. I would suggest you follow this post and do things again:
[linking a static library to an iOS project](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6124523/linking-a-static-library-to-an-ios-project-in-xcode-4)

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you've missed the part of the readme that tells you to add some "Framework Search Paths" settings - you need to add a couple of things to your build settings. Alternatively, just copy the "Empty CocoaLibSpotify Project" sample project, rename it and off you go.

Answer (score 0):

CocoaLibSpotify is available as a CocoaPod.

[Install CocoaPods](http://cocoapods.org/)

Add the following line to your PodFile

```
pod 'CocoaLibSpotify', '~> 2.4.4'
```

In Terminal go to your project's root and execute

```
pod install
```

Include this header to use CocoaLibSpotify

```
#import "CocoaLibSpotify.h"
```

Cocoapods is an easy way to manage dependencies. I have successfully included CocoaLibSpotify in my projects using this method.