# I built webRTC but uncertain how to put it into project

Tags: objective-c, frameworks, webrtc

So, the new webRTC has getCaptureSession, but cocoa pod version is old, and doesn't have it. I really could use that session. So I have a few options, 2 of which are "wait for cocoa pods" (not gonna happen), or 2) "Place library into project".

My main problem is, even though I somehow managed to build the libs for sim and device, I do not know if pasting just libwebrtc.a would work, and even so, I can't find the header files that go with it.

I fear my question comes from a lack of understanding of libraries more than this particular library, so I tried to make it generalized towards that. I do understand enough to add, create, fix bugs with adding most libs.

The sample project only has one .a file (libwebrtc), and google doesn't use the usual XCode workflow, so I spend inordinate amounts of time trying to figure out Google's custom tooling. (Try googling how to use Gyp files - I get they make xcodeprojects, and I can see the specs, but how to run them?)

Just to reiterate, I have successfully built the libs, but uncertain how to paste and get the header with the function I'm after, in the file avfoundationvideocapturer.h from Google's webRTC issue 4070 - so yes, it's in there.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to add it to the project as a file. Then include it in the `Link Binary With Libraries` section in the `Build Phases` of your target configuration.

Take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6124523/linking-a-static-library-to-an-ios-project-in-xcode-4).

For the header files, have a look at [this](http://ninjanetic.com/how-to-get-started-with-webrtc-and-ios-without-wasting-10-hours-of-your-life/). Header files are under `src/talk/app/webrtc/objc/public/*.h` or something like that.

Comment: I built webRTC, the main thing I'm not getting is 1) Why the sample projects only have one libWebRTC.a and I have 3 (2x device 1x sim), and where the header files are supposed to go if I drag over the .a. 

I've imported MailCore and a few other libraries successfully, but their prepackaging leaves out details, sans the directory path relative/absolute

Comment: You have to separately drag in the .a and the .h files into your project.